# Possible stack corruption inside try __finally block

Tags: c++, try-finally, c++builder-5

I am having problems with stack corruption in a new module I am working on which is part of a large legacy project.  My code is written in C++ using Borland C++Builder 5.0.

I have tracked the problem to the following function:

```
// Note: Class TMarshalServerClientThread has the following objects defined
// CRITICAL_SECTION                 FCriticalSection;
// std::vector<TMarshalTagInfo*>    FTagChangeQueue;

void __fastcall TMarshalServerClientThread::SendChangeNotifications()
{
   EnterCriticalSection(FCriticalSection);

   try {
      if (FTagChangeQueue.size() == 0) {         
         return;
      }

      // Process items in change queue

      FTagChangeQueue.clear();

   } __finally {
      LeaveCriticalSection(FCriticalSection);
   }
}
```

This function is called in the context of a worker thread (which descends from TThread).  A different thread populates the change queue with data as it becomes available.  The change queue is protected by a critical section object.

When the code is run, I sporadically get access violations when attempting to leave the critical section.  From what I can tell, sometimes when the **__finally** section is entered, the stack is corrupted.  The class instance on the heap is fine, but the pointers to the class (such as the "this" pointer) appear to be invalid.

If I remove the call to return if the change queue is empty, the problem goes away.  Additionally, the code to process the items in the queue is not the source of the problem, as I can comment it out and the problem remains.

So my question is are there known issues when using **__finally** in C++Builder 5?  Is it wrong to call **return** from within a **try __finally** block?  If so, why?

Please note that I realize that there are different/better ways to do what I am doing, and I am refactoring as such.  However, I fail to see why this codes should be causing stack corruption.

Comment: Where is your catch block?

Comment: @duDE - There is no catch block in the function.  Any exceptions which occur in this function are caught and handled by its caller.

Answer (score 1):

As @duDE pointed, you should use pair of **__*try, _*_finally** instead of intermixing C++ **try**, and Borland extension **__finally**.

Comment: I'll see if that works.  The examples in the Borland documentation show the use of **try/__finally**, and also seem to imply that **try** and **__try** can be used interchangeably.  But then, it wouldn't be the first time that the documentation is incorrect...

Comment: The same problem occurs using **__try/__finally** and **try/__finally**

Comment: Mixing `try` with `__finallý` works just fine in general. IIRC, earlier versions of BCB, which might include BCB5, had problems with `return` inside of a `try`/`__finally` block. For that reason, I always avoid that, even in later versions. In this situation I would suggest dropping the `try`/`__finally` altogether and use an RAII wrapper instead.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a long time after the original question was posted, but as a warning to others, I can vouch for the symptom that Jonathan Wiens is reporting.  I experienced it with Builder XE4.  It does not happen frequently, but it seems that Borland/Embarcadero's implementation of **try / finally** blocks in a multi-threaded process very occasionally corrupts the stack.  I was also using critical sections, although that may be coincidental.

I was able to resolve my problem by discarding the **try / finally**.  I was fortunate that I was only deleting class instances in the **finally** block, so I was able to replace the **try / finally** with scope braces, using **std::auto_ptr** fields to delete the objects in question.